# PC wont boot up after high voltage fluctuation

Tags: desktop-computer

Two days ago, I was working on my PC and I saved my files and shut down the system properly and went out for an hour or more. When I came back and tried to turn on my PC, the blue power light of my PC along with DVD-RW flashed for a second and then turn off again. And this went into a loop. **The PC didn't boot up. PC was not connected to a CVT, voltage stablizer or UPS.**
*"Neighbours told me that there was a high voltage fluctuation for a second due to which their TV, Bulbs and other electrical equipment failed."*

I opened up cabinet of PC to see that what exactly issue is. Here are my troubleshooting steps:- 1. I took out the CMOS battery to reset CMOS settings and then inserted the battery again and tried to start PC. But problem remained same.

I saw that my CPU fan wasn't working so I took it out and tried to connect it on other PC. but it worked.

I tested if PSU fan is working or not and found that PSU fan is also working properly.

Now I am not able to figure out that what exactly the issue is. Even now the PC is going in same loop when I start it up.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically your PSU takes the brunt of something like that. Swap out your PSU. I'd guess some *specific* rail failed, or some internal component, its trying to power up and failing.

The PSU fan 'working' dosen't mean very much. Try a known good PSU first. With a modern PC as long as there's power you should get *some* sort of error indication.

Comment: Thanks a lot..... Its fixed after I changed my PSU. Its working perfectly fine now.